# UICollectionView is not displaying - bug?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am a bit of a novice with swift. I am trying to simply create a collection view that is placed within a specific region of the screen (landscape iPad iOS). It is possible that there is actually a collectionView bug... The following code produces the attached image. The problem is that the entirety of the collection view simply isn't displayed...

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    var collectionView: UICollectionView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 300, left: 500, bottom: 30, right: 10)
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 32, height: 32)
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView!.dataSource = self
        collectionView!.delegate = self
        collectionView!.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        collectionView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.view.addSubview(collectionView!)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 40
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
        return cell
    }
}
```

[image: iOS simulator]

Also, is there a way I can avoid using a FLOW LAYOUT? A rigid collection view is fine. I need a 10x10 collection view that won't vary in size or number of cells.

Comment: Your `UIEdgeInsets` are **huge**. Try something smaller. For example, `layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 50, left: 50, bottom: 50, right: 50)`

Comment: Thanks for the response - maybe my understanding of UIEdgeInsets is wrong. Your recommendation helps, but lets say I want my collection within the bottom right corner - This is where I am getting the problem. If my screen dimensions are 1024x768, I would think that my edge insets should be something like (top: 500, left: 500, bottom: 0, right: 0)... no? Wouldn't this get me a collection view in the bottom right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you're trying to achieve using auto layout sounds like it would be your best option. You could alternatively set your `UICollectionView`'s frame to be in the bottom right corner like so:

```
collectionView!.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width - collectionView!.frame.size.width, y: self.view.frame.size.height - collectionView!.frame.size.height, width: 400, height: 400)
```

But this is more of a temporary fix and would have to be considered for each device's, and future device's, layout.